# Finding next instance of class name outside of parent div of div clicked?

Tags: jquery

If you have

```
<div id="sf_53" class="req">
    <div class="expF"><a href="#">CLICK HERE</a></div>
</div>
<div class="exp"></div>
```

and your click function was activated by "expF", how do you add html to the next instance of "exp"?

I thought knowing the main parent div would make it like

```
$("#sf_53").nextAll(".exp").html("Howdy!");
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.closest()` with `.next()`:

```
 $(this).closest('.req').next().html('somehtml');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J7mJX/56/)**

Comment: Thank you both - I'd been all around it for about 45 mins - but no cigar!!! These both work perfectly.

Comment: @Shaun: glad it helps shaun

Answer (score 1):

Since `id` must be unique, you can just use **[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** to get the next immediate sibling of `#sf_53` element which is `.exp` div:

```
$('.expF').click(function() {
    $('#sf_53').next().html("Howdy"!);
});
```